# Passing code from CodePipeline to PythonFunction

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create a CDK app that will deploy a pipeline-stack and a lambda-stack. Similar to the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html). I'm trying to implement a basic CI/CD application that is triggered with every push to a Github Enterprise Repo.

I chose to use PythonFunction from (@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python) instead of function from @aws-cdk/aws-lambda because PythonFunction builds the dependencies from requirements.txt. I have various lambdas that use different packages (like awswrangler, pandas, requests, etc.).

But, PythonFunction does not support CfnParametersCode (Where the code is passed through CDK instead of being read from an asset).

- What other option do I have to pass my code from GithubEnterprise to
  the PythonFunction?
- If function from @aws-cdk/aws-lambda is the only option I have, how
  can I include the packages from requirements.txt
- [This](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda#bundling-asset-code) does seem like an option for @aws-cdl/aws-lambda, but how would I pass my code from Github? This example relates to building from asset code.

I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, I just started working with AWS CDK last week.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend to take a look at [pipelines.CdkPipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html) which is able to deal with Assets. That means you can directly use `lambda.Code.from_asset` instead of overriding `CfnParametersCode` in the Pipeline.

Regarding your other question, you can deal with the requirements by installing them into your lambda folder during the build step with: `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .`

Answer (score 0):

`CfnParametersCode` gives you the ability to upload your code from an S3 file.
You can do the same via `lambda.Code.fromBucket`.

Taking your link from the third point (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda#bundling-asset-code) You just need to use `lambda.Code.fromBucket` instead of `code: lambda.Code.fromAsset`. Docs can be found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda

Comment: Thanks for the reply saart. Could you provide a resource for uploading code to s3 bucket please. I could not find it

Comment: Here are samples from several runtimes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html